# Refining edge and contour detection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator

I am struggling to get good results detecting objects with a series of images I have. The issue is that they are similar objects with a bit of real world noise (in this case bunches of bananas). Having them overlapping is probably not helping.

My approach has been this tried and tested classic:
 - Convert to grayscale
 - Blur the image slightly
 - Apply Canny edge detection
 - Dilate the image
 - Find the contours

Right now I have been trying to do a Canny edge detection but the edges aren't quite right and so when I find the contours I get all sorts of funny shapes (and only sometimes the bananas).

I have also tried Sobel edge detection with even poorer results.

example pic before contour detection:

[image: example pic before contour detection]

example pic after contour detection:

[image: example pic after contour detection]

Can somebody please give me some suggestions on how I can refine this?

Comment: DO you want to segment the bunch as a whole or each individual banana?

Comment: Do you want the whole region like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eNrk.png ?

Comment: why convert to greyscale? surely the colour information would be useful in this case

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer - I am after each individual banana. It doesn't even have to be terribly accurate, I would be happy with detecting just 2 or 3 bananas clearly out of the bunch

Comment: @nkjt - I have tried it both with greyscale and not and both results are fairly similar